# Как работает auto в CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Как высчитывается значение `auto` в `CSS`? Написано, что зависит от того, где это `auto` стоит. То есть, если написано `width:auto` — это один принцип расчета, если `margin-top:auto`, `margin-bottom:auto` — другой… В голове каша с этим `auto`. Например, если задать блоку `position: absolute` + задана ширина `width:**px` + задать `margin-top:auto`, `margin-bottom:auto`+ задать `top: 0px, bottom: 0px, left: 0px, right: 0px` - блок выровняется по середине по высоте. Если же убрать, например, `top: 0px`, то `margin` по вертикали вообще пропадет и не будет выравнивания по высоте.

То есть, у меня нет понимания системы работы `auto`. Может быть, кто-то из вас уже систематизировал это дело. Помогите, пожалуйста, систематизировать то, как в каком случае работает `auto` в `CSS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение определённого свойства `auto` работает в зависимости от применяемого свойства и контекста (значений других свойств).

Это всё записано в стандартах, к примеру в [этом по поводу `margin` и `height` для абсолютно позиционируемых элементов](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height). Там об этом записано так

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> 'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' +
>   'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom'
>   = height of containing block
>
> If all three of 'top', 'height', and 'bottom' are auto, set 'top' to
>   the static position and apply rule number three below.
>
> If none of the three are 'auto': **If both 'margin-top' and
>   'margin-bottom' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra
>   constraint that the two margins get equal values.** If one of
>   'margin-top' or 'margin-bottom' is 'auto', solve the equation for that
>   value. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for
>   'bottom' and solve for that value.

Это значит, что если `top`, `height` и `bottom` установлены не в `auto` (это значение по умолчанию для этих свойств), то `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` занимают оставшееся пространство (*the two margins get equal values* в спецификации).

Comment: я уже читал в стандарте именно этот кусок, который вы написали. если задать блоку position: absolute + задана ширина width:**px + задать margin-top:auto, margin-bottom:auto+ задать top: 0px, bottom: 0px, left: 0px, right: 0px - блок выровняется по середине по высоте. Если же убрать, например, top: 0px, то margin по вертикали вообще пропадет и не будет выравнивания по высоте.

Comment: как это объяснить?

Comment: хорошо. сможете ответить на этот вопрос, используя стандарт, который привели? у меня не получилось

Comment: @Dimon Тем для `top` применяется значение `auto` по умолчанию и не работает уже фрагмент *"If none of the three are 'auto'…"*.